# Unable to push a local directory to GitHub using LibGit2Sharp

Tags: github, libgit2sharp

I need to push a local folder to a Git repository. Following is what I have tried till now:

```
public static async Task CommitAllChanges(string message,string filePath, string cloneUrl)
    {
        try
        {
            var _folder = new DirectoryInfo(filePath);
            string path = LibGit2Sharp.Repository.Init(_folder.FullName);
            using (var repo = new LibGit2Sharp.Repository(path))
            {                    
                var files = _folder.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(f => f.FullName);
                Commands.Stage(repo, "*");

                repo.Commit(message, new LibGit2Sharp.Signature("sormita", "sormita@gmail.com", DateTimeOffset.Now),
                     new LibGit2Sharp.Signature("sormita", "sormita@gmail.com", DateTimeOffset.Now));

                //push files                
                string name = "origin";
                repo.Network.Remotes.Add(name, cloneUrl);
                var remote = repo.Network.Remotes.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name == name);

                var options = new PushOptions
                {
                    CredentialsProvider = (_url, _user, _cred) =>
                        new UsernamePasswordCredentials { Username = "email", Password = "password" }
                };

                string pushRefSpec = @"refs/heads/master";

                repo.Network.Push(remote, pushRefSpec, options);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        
        
    }
```

I am able to push but no files are shown in the repository in GitHub.

The above code will successfully push a directory to Github repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I use GitHub PAT token for this Push?

Set that as your password to the credentials provider.  A PAT is a password.

And if you've used your *actual* password in your question, please **change it immediately**.

Comment: The damage is done, editing the question doesn't actually help, SO has editing history, so you should ask him/her to change his/her password.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to my question code details for full implementation of how to push a local directory to GitHub repository.